# Creating Rest API using Node.js, Express, and MongoDB .post() error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api, rest

I'm attempting to create a Rest API using Node.js, Express, and MongoDB. I am currently running on my local host :3000. When I try to restart and run the server I am getting this error:

Error: `.post() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]`

Attached below is my code.

I am new to this, not sure what that error is or how to fix. Thanks in advance!

server.js

```
var express = require('express'),
drink = require('./routes/drinks');

var app = express();

app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));     /* 'default', 'short', 'tiny', 'dev' */
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    });

app.get('/drinks', drink.findAll);
app.get('/drinks/:id', drink.findById);
app.post('/drinks', drink.addWine);
app.put('/drinks/:id', drink.updateWine);
app.delete('/drinks/:id', drink.deleteWine);

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Listening on port 3000...');
```

drinks.js

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');

var Server = mongo.Server,
    Db = mongo.Db,
    BSON = mongo.BSONPure;

var server = new Server('localhost', 27017, {auto_reconnect: true});
db = new Db('drinkdb', server);

db.open(function(err, db) {
    if(!err) {
        console.log("Connected to 'drinkdb' database");
        db.collection('drinks', {strict:true}, function(err, collection) {
            if (err) {
            console.log("The 'drinks' collection doesn't exist. Creating it with sample data...");
            populateDB();
            }
        });
    }
    });

exports.findById = function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    console.log('Retrieving drink: ' + id);
    db.collection('drinks', function(err, collection) {
        collection.findOne({'_id':new BSON.ObjectID(id)}, function(err, item) {
            res.send(item);
        });
    });
};

exports.findAll = function(req, res) {
    db.collection('drinks', function(err, collection) {
        collection.find().toArray(function(err, items) {
            res.send(items);
        });
    });
};

exports.addDrink = function(req, res) {
    var drink = req.body;
    console.log('Adding drink: ' + JSON.stringify(drink));
    db.collection('drinks', function(err, collection) {
        collection.insert(drink, {safe:true}, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
            res.send({'error':'An error has occurred'});
            } else {
            console.log('Success: ' + JSON.stringify(result[0]));
            res.send(result[0]);
            }
        });
    });
};

exports.updateDrink = function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    var drink = req.body;
    console.log('Updating drink: ' + id);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(drink));
    db.collection('drinks', function(err, collection) {
        collection.update({'_id':new BSON.ObjectID(id)}, drink, {safe:true}, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error updating drink: ' + err);
                res.send({'error':'An error has occurred'});
            } else {
                console.log('' + result + ' document(s) updated');
                res.send(drink);
            }
        });
    });
};

exports.deleteDrink = function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    console.log('Deleting drink: ' + id);
    db.collection('drinks', function(err, collection) {
        collection.remove({'_id':new BSON.ObjectID(id)}, {safe:true}, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
            res.send({'error':'An error has occurred - ' + err});
            } else {
            console.log('' + result + ' document(s) deleted');
            res.send(req.body);
            }
        });
    });
};

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
// Populate database with sample data -- Only used once: the first time the application is started.
// You'd typically not find this code in a real-life app, since the database would already exist.
var populateDB = function() {

    var drinks = [{
        id: "1",
        name: "Margarita",
        //ingredients: ["Tequila","Lime juice","Triple Sec","Lime","Salt","Ice"],
        //measurements: ["2 oz","1 oz","1 oz","1","optional","optional"],
        directions: "Shake the other ingredients with ice, then carefully pour into the glass. Served: On the rocks; poured over ice. Optional: Salt the rim of the glass by rubbing lime on it so it sticks."
    },{
        id: "2",
        name: "Strawberry Margarita",
        //ingredients: ["Tequila", "Lime juice","Triple Sec","Strawberries","Lime","Salt", "Ice"],
        //measurements: ["2 oz","1 oz", "1 oz", "3 1/2 cups", "1", "optional", "optional"],
        directions: "Combine strawberries, ice, tequila, lime juice, and triple sec in a blender, and process until the mixture is smooth. Carefully pour into the glass. Served: On the rocks; poured over ice. Optional: Salt the rim of the glass by rubbing lime on it so it sticks."
    }];

    db.collection('drinks', function(err, collection) {
        collection.insert(drinks, {safe:true}, function(err, result) {});
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see in the drinks.js you are exporting addDrink function but in the server.js you are trying to use undefined addWine function.

Try to rename Wine to Drink in server.js routes handlers.